# Converting from Algebraic notation to Coordinate notation

Tags: programming, notation

I saw this thread: [Converting square notation to algebraic notation programmatically](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/converting-square-notation-to-algebraic-notation-programmatically)

Unfortunately, it's the reverse of what I need to do.

Given a FEN and an Algebraic move, I need to generate the coordinate notation of said move.

I realize that you need the position (FEN) in order to reverse engineer the starting position of the pawn/piece being moved.

I'm hoping there is some utility or library/function that does this. If not, a description/outline of the basic algorithm would be great too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily in python using the [python-chess](https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/) module and using the [`parse_san` function of `chess.Move.`](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#chess.Board.parse_san)

Let's call the script `algebTocoord.py`:

```
import chess

testfen = 'rnbqkb1r/pppppppp/5n2/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 1 2'
board = chess.Board(testfen)
algmove = 'Nf3'
coordmove = str(board.parse_san(algmove))
print coordmove
```

the printed output is:

```
'g1f3'
```

This was tested using Python version `2.7.16` and the `0.22.1` version of python-chess.